# Creating a database, a table within the database and inserting some values into it in one go

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, database

I've written a script which creates a `new database`, a `table` within the database, `insert some values` into it and `fetch the values` in one go. The way I've created the script below to achieve what I just said seems not to be an ideal way as there are too many repetitions in there. To be specific this two functions `create_database()` and `connect()` are almost identical. Moreover, I had to use `mycursor = conn.cursor()` twice within main function.

```
import mysql.connector

def create_database():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      passwd = "",
      database=""
    )
    return mydb

def connect(databasename):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      passwd = "",
      database=databasename
    )
    return mydb

def store_data(item_name,item_link):
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO webdata (item_name,item_link) VALUES (%s,%s)", (item_name,item_link))
    conn.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db_name = "newdatabase"
    conn = create_database()
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        mycursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {db_name}")
    except mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError:
        pass
    conn = connect(db_name)
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("DROP TABLE if exists webdata")
    mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists webdata (item_name VARCHAR(255), item_link VARCHAR(255))")
    store_data("all questions","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping")
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM webdata")
    for item in mycursor.fetchall():
        print(item)
```

What it prints (expected result):

```
('all questions', 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the title alone, this sounds like something that should not be done, particularly since this is not a lightweight database such as SQLite. Creating the database, its tables, columns, constraints etc. is not, and should not, be the job of the application - but rather an external setup script with administrative permissions. The application, then, should not have such permissions and should only be able to insert/select/update/delete.

For some reason I thought autocommit is enabled by default for the MySQL Python connector, but apparently it's not:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

So your explicit call to `commit` is fine.

I can't tell from the documentation whether the cursor and connection objects support context management. Try putting both of those in `with` statements, and if it complains that there's no `__enter__`, switch to a `try/finally` that guarantees cursor and connection closure.

Comment: It seems [you concluded in 2020](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/240938/52915) that context management is not supported by default. According to the bugtracker, the functionality has been added since then. However, it might be a good idea to double-check that.

Answer (score 2):

Python functions can have optional arguments with default values. If you adjust
the signature of `connect()` to have a default, the `create_database()`
function will be unnecessary.

```
def connect(database_name = ''):
    return mysql.connector.connect(
      host = 'localhost',
      user = 'root',
      passwd = '',
      database = database_name
    )
```

Contrary to your question text, you don't have a main function; you just have
top-level code nested under an if-conditional. Top-level code (other than
constants or imports) is generally a bad idea because it is inflexible and not
easily tested or experimented with. Move that code into a proper
`main()` function, and then just invoke it in the if-conditional. It's also not
a bad idea to prepare for the future of your script by including the
ability to handle simple command-line arguments -- often handy for debugging and
experimentation even if they are never part of an intended use case of the script.

```
import sys

def main(args):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

After you make that change, the `store_data()` function will be broken, because
it depends on having access to the global `mycursor` variable. That's another
illustration of the problems with top-level code: it can camouflage dependencies
and, in some cases, create situations that are difficult to debug and disentangle if
the volume of such code grows large enough. Instead, the `store_data()` function
should take the DB connection as an explicit argument.

A rigorous approach
of putting all code inside of functions will seem like a small hassle at first;
but in my experience, it nearly always pays off in the form of fewer
bugs, greater flexibility, improved code readability, and various other
benefits.